# A matter of style

Tags: c++, coding-style

Would you write something like:

```
enum XYZ_TYPE {X=1, Y=2, Z=3};
```

I saw it and the suffix _TYPE confuses me in the enum context.  There is a strong prospect that it is because I am not bright.

Comment: How about using a convention like `enum eXyz { X = 1, Y, Z };`. The prefix `e` can then always identify the type as an enum. I forgot what this naming convention was called...

Comment: @themoondothshine: depending on who you ask, either "hungarian notation" or "idiocy". The latter is by far the most common, and has been for quite a few years now.

Comment: @jalf: There's a lot I gotta learn!! :)  So which notation in your opinion makes more sense? Currently (as you may have noticed) I use camel-case and C-style naming conventions...

Comment: @themoondothshine: both  of those are fine. I tend to use the C-style one because it better matches the standard libtary, but both are fine. Just don't add explicit type prefixes like eMyEnum and cMyClass or mMyMember or iMyInt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with that suffix as enums are types of their own, they simply are not type safe.

```
XYZ_TYPE myXYZ = X;
if(myXYZ == 1) { } //This is what I meant by not strongly typed.
```

C++0x fixes enums so they are strongly typed though.

Just follow whatever your coding standard says about enum type names.  In the end it doesn't matter as long as it is consistent with your coding standard, and it is logically sound.

Comment: That helps a lot Brian.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I would not write it just like that, but it's hardly a make-or-break situation.  Roll with the punches and save your frustration for things that really deserve it, like [for-case loops](http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/The_FOR-CASE_paradigm.aspx).  :)

Comment: the for-case loop is priceless! absolute gem!

Answer (score 2):

I already have a preferred convention to distinguish types from other identifiers, which is that I use CamelCase with an initial capital for types and lower-case for others. Constants can be all-caps, including enum values.

But "XYZ_TYPE" with any capitalisation is kind of a poor name for an enumeration. I'd use `enum Color {RED=1, GREEN=2, BLUE=3};`, or `enum FuzzyBool {yes=1, no=2, filenotfound=3};`, or some such. Not REDGREENBLUE_TYPE.

I think in general if your names are well-chosen then you shouldn't need a _TYPE suffix. If your names aren't well chosen, and to be fair it can be difficult, then maybe you need it to distinguish the type from an object of that type. Maybe. But I prefer to use case.

Comment: So the question is, if XYZ_TYPE is the type, then what else is XYZ being used for that means the type couldn't be called XYZ?

Answer (score 1):

XYZ_TYPE is just another name that follows the C++ variable-naming conventions, though I would prefer to use all capital names for preprocessor definitions.

Comment: XYZ_TYPE is not a variable name... It is an enum type name.

Answer (score 0):

We'd just call it an `XYZ`, making it follow our convention of naming types in CamelCase with a leading capital letter.  The enumerated values would be `eX`, `eY`, and `eZ`, following out convention of naming values and variables in CamelCase with a leading lowercase letter, and our convention of all enum values starting with `e` (constants start with `k`, and there are no other prefixes in general use.  We use a very limited set of Light Side Hungarian.)

As with all conventions, your mileage may vary.  But suffixing types with `_TYPE` seems like a beginner's technique that adds little value for the visual clutter it costs.